# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerFactory - Spring Batch

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am developing `Spring Batch- MultiResourceItemReader & HibernateItemWriter` example. I am able to successfully compile the code, but when trying to run it I see following error is comming, not sure what is going wrong here.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:context-model.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [spring-batch-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [context-model.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:165)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.websystique.springbatch.Main.main(Main.java:16)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [context-model.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:223)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory
```

ExamResult.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXAM_RESULT")
public class ExamResult {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "STUDENT_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String studentName;

    @Column(name = "DOB", nullable = false)
    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
    private LocalDate dob;

    @Column(name = "PERCENTAGE", nullable = false)
    private double percentage;
    // setters and getters
}
```

ExamResultFieldSetMapper.java

```
public class ExamResultFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<ExamResult>{

    public ExamResult mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
        ExamResult result = new ExamResult();
        result.setStudentName(fieldSet.readString(0));
        result.setDob(new LocalDate(fieldSet.readDate(1,"dd/MM/yyyy")));
        result.setPercentage(fieldSet.readDouble(2));
        return result;
    }
}
```

ExamResultItemProcessor.java

```
public class ExamResultItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<ExamResult, ExamResult> {

    @Override
    public ExamResult process(ExamResult result) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Processing result :"+result);
        if(result.getPercentage() < 60){
            return null;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

ExamResultJobListener.java

```
public class ExamResultJobListener implements JobExecutionListener{

    private DateTime startTime, stopTime;

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        startTime = new DateTime();
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");
        System.out.println("ExamResult Job starts at :"+startTime);
    }


    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        stopTime = new DateTime();
        System.out.println("ExamResult Job stops at :"+stopTime);
        System.out.println("Total time take in millis :"+getTimeInMillis(startTime , stopTime));
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");


        if(jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED){
            System.out.println("ExamResult job completed successfully");
            //Here you can perform some other business logic like cleanup
        }else if(jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.FAILED){
            System.out.println("ExamResult job failed with following exceptions ");
            List<Throwable> exceptionList = jobExecution.getAllFailureExceptions();
            for(Throwable th : exceptionList){
                System.err.println("exception :" +th.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private long getTimeInMillis(DateTime start, DateTime stop){
        return stop.getMillis() - start.getMillis();
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String areg[]){

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-batch-context.xml");

        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("examResultJob");

        try {
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            System.out.println("Job Exit Status : "+ execution.getStatus());

        } catch (JobExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println("Job ExamResult failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

context-datasource.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver.class.name}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

context-model.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"
                             default-autowire="byName"  default-init-method="init">

    <import resource="classpath:context-datasource.xml"/>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.websystique.springbatch.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop> -->
            </props>
        </property>     
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

spring-batch-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:context-model.xml"/>


    <!-- JobRepository and JobLauncher are configuration/setup classes -->
    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean" />

    <bean id="jobLauncher"  class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>

    <!-- =============  Multi Resource Item Reader  ================== -->
    <bean id="multiResourceItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
        <property name="resources" value="classpath:csv/ExamResult*.txt" />
        <property name="delegate" ref="flatFileItemReader" />
    </bean>


    <!-- =========== ItemReader reads a complete line one by one from input file ============-->
    <bean id="flatFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">

        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">

                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <!-- Mapper which maps each individual items in a record to properties in POJO -->
                    <bean class="com.websystique.springbatch.ExamResultFieldSetMapper" />
                </property>

                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <!-- A tokenizer class to be used when items in input record are separated by specific characters -->
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="delimiter" value="|" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <!-- ItemWriter which writes data to database -->
    <bean id="databaseItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemWriter">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Optional ItemProcessor to perform business logic/filtering on the input records -->
    <bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.websystique.springbatch.ExamResultItemProcessor" />

    <!-- Optional JobExecutionListener to perform business logic before and after the job -->
    <bean id="jobListener" class="com.websystique.springbatch.ExamResultJobListener" />


    <!-- =========== Actual Job =========== -->
    <batch:job id="examResultJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                <batch:chunk reader="multiResourceItemReader" writer="databaseItemWriter"
                    processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="10" />
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="jobListener" />
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:job>
</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <springframework.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springbatch.version>3.0.1.RELEASE</springbatch.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <!-- <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version> -->
        <javassist.version>3.18.1-GA</javassist.version>
        <!-- <javassist.version>3.20.0-GA</javassist.version> -->
        <mysql.version>5.1.31</mysql.version>
        <joda-time.version>2.3</joda-time.version>
        <c3p0.version>0.9.5-pre8</c3p0.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring TX -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring ORM support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Batch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springbatch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>${springbatch.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate related dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>${javassist.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Joda-Time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ComboPooledDataSource -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use this. I like Spring Batch. Hope this will work nicely.

```
<springframework.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Or you can use latest versions like below

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <springframework.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <!-- <springbatch.version>3.0.1.RELEASE</springbatch.version> -->
        <springbatch.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</springbatch.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <!-- <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version> -->
        <javassist.version>3.18.1-GA</javassist.version>
        <!-- <javassist.version>3.20.0-GA</javassist.version> -->
        <mysql.version>5.1.31</mysql.version>
        <joda-time.version>2.3</joda-time.version>
        <c3p0.version>0.9.5-pre8</c3p0.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring TX -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring ORM support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Web - Added Newly -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring Batch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springbatch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>${springbatch.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate related dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>${javassist.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Joda-Time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ComboPooledDataSource -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```